# React-Native, How to create draggable diamond shape view

Tags: react-native, npm, shapes

I want to create diamond shape view with dragable action, please check this video.
[video link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k1ynRLD58uKfhpLtLW8uOdK2glOgRvSK)

Please, suggest me library or any thing else.

Thanks.

Comment: I would first check the SVG library https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg and a view with pan responder on it https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder. On panResponder you catch the dragging, and update the state to re-render the SVG.

Comment: Thanks for replay, let me check your suggestion..